# RESTful backend API for user account

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express.js

I have made a RESTful API built with Node.js, Express, Basic-auth and Mongoose. it will respond JSON.

This is the folder structure:

> ```
> .
> ├── index.js
> ├── lib
> │   ├── middleware
> │   │   ├── Authentication.js
> │   │   └── index.js
> │   ├── routes
> │   │   ├── Account.js
> │   │   └── index.js
> │   └── schemas
> │       └── Account.js
> ├── node_modules
> ```

This is the planned endpoint:

> ```
>         URI         |          GET             |     POST       |            PUT               |    DELETE
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> /account            | Get all document         | Add a document |              -               |          -
> /account/:id        | Get a document           |       -        | Update a document            | Delete a document
> ```

**index.js**

```js
var app = require('express')();
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var middleware = require('./lib/middleware');
var routes = require('./lib/routes');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(middleware.Authentication);

app.post('/account', routes.insertAccount);
app.get('/account', routes.getAccounts);
app.get('/account/:id', routes.getAccountById);
app.put('/account/:id', routes.updateAccountById);
app.delete('/account/:id', routes.deleteAccountById);

app.listen(8000), function(){
    console.log('Server starts on http://localhost:8000');
};
```

The middleware **Authentication.js**:

```js
var auth = require('basic-auth');

module.exports.Authentication = function(req, res, next){
    var credentials = auth(req);
    if (!credentials ||
        credentials.name !== 'admin' ||
        credentials.pass !== 'rahasia'){
        return res.status(401).json({status: 'login required'});
    }

    next();
}
```

The middleware **index.js**:

```js
module.exports = require('./Authentication');
```

The routes **Account.js**:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var accountSchema = require('../schemas/Account')
var Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/account');

module.exports.getAccounts = function(req, res){
    var query = Account.find({});
    query.exec(function(err, docs){
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        res.json(docs);
    });
}

module.exports.getAccountById = function(req, res){
    var query = Account.findById(req.params.id);
    query.exec(function(err, doc){
        if (err) {
            res.status(500)
                .json({
                    task: 'get one account',
                    param: req.params.id,
                    status: 'fail',
                    error: err
                });

            return console.error(err);
        }

        if (doc === null) {
            return res.json({
                task: 'get one account',
                param: req.params.id,
                status: 'Not found'
            });
        }

        res.json(doc);
    });
}

module.exports.updateAccountById = function(req, res){
    var query = Account.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body);
    query.exec(function(err, raw){
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        if (raw === null) {
            return res.status(500)
                .json({
                    task: 'update',
                    status: 'fail'
                });
        }

        res.json({
            task: 'update',
            param: req.body,
            status: 'ok',
            data: raw
        });
    });
}

module.exports.insertAccount = function(req, res){
    var query = Account.create(req.body, function(err, doc){
        if (err) {
            res.status(500)
                .json({
                    task: 'insert',
                    status: 'fail',
                    error: err
                });

            return console.error(err);
        }

        res.json({
            task: 'insert',
            status: 'ok',
            data: doc
        });
    });
}

module.exports.deleteAccountById = function(req, res){
    var query = Account.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
    query.exec(function(err, doc){
        if (err) {
            res.status(500)
                .json({
                    task: 'delete',
                    id: req.params.id,
                    status: 'fail',
                    error: err
                });

            return console.error(err);
        }

        if (doc === null) {
            return res.status(500)
                    .json({
                        task: 'delete',
                        id: req.params.id,
                        status: 'fail'
                    });
        }

        res.json({
            task: 'delete',
            status: 'ok',
            removed: doc
        });
    });
}
```

The routes **index.js**:

```js
module.exports = require('./Account');
```

The schemas **Account.js**:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var validator = require('validator');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var accountSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Nama wajib diisi.']
    },
    title: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        required: [true, 'Email wajib diisi.'],
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function(value){
                return validator.isEmail(value);
            },
            message: '{VALUE} Bukan email yang sah.'
        }
    },
    phone: Number,
    address: {
        type: String,
        text: true
    },
    company: {
        type: String,
        text: true
    }
});

module.exports = accountSchema;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just few suggestions

1. Split your database access logic into dao, and since you're using mongoose you can write static or instance methods on top of your schema.
2. For authentication i would suggest you have a look at passport.js they have many strategies which you can implement **basic,bearer,openId** etc, if you need an example let me know.
3. Try using **promises** instead of **callbacks**, mongoose already supports promises will help you in writing more manageable code.